# Is it possible to unset git config entries ad-hoc

Tags: git

I can set different config options on a per-command basis with git using the `-c` (or `--config`) option, e.g.

```
git -c interactive.diffFilter=cat add -i
```

Is there a way to also *unset* a config option?

Certain behaviors in git are triggered by the mere presence of a config option, and without a way to unset options there is no way to invoke the default behavior.

In my case I have `diff.external` but occasionally want to also view the built-in diff output.

I know I can just edit the config file, but I'm interested in not doing that.

Comment: Is `--no-ext-diff` what you want in that specific case?

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround would be to omit the value in `-c setting=`:

```
git -c interactive.diffFilter= add -i
```

For instance, this would return nothing:

```
git -c user.name= config user.name
```

For boolean settings, that would set it to `false`, according to [`git` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--cltnamegtltvaluegt).

As noted in the comments, that does not *unset*, but override the value with an empty one.
For [`diff.external`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-diffexternal), you would get

```bash
git -c diff.external= diff
error: cannot spawn : No such file or directory
fatal: external diff died, stopping at INSTALL
```

That means it is best to use a `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` environment variable by default, because you can easily unset an environment variable:

```
GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF= git diff
```

Comment: This does not however seem to _unset_ the value. for `diff.external` this means git will try and execute the command ` ` (the empty string), which fails (obviously)

Comment: @plc Good point, I have made that visible in the answer, and provided with an alternative solution.